# Cloud Run: 500 Server Error with no log output

Tags: google-cloud-run

We are investigating an issue on a deployed cloud run service, where requests made to the service occasionnaly fail with a `StatusCodeError: 500`, while no log of said requests appear on cloud run.

Served requests usually produce two log lines detailing the request, route and exit code (`POST 200 on https://service-name.a.run.app/route/...`)

- One with log name `projects/XXX/logs/run.googleapis.com/stdout` is produced by our application to log the serving of every request
- One with log name `projects/XXX/logs/run.googleapis.com/requests` is automatically produced by cloud run on every request

When the incident occurs, **none** of those are logged. The client (running in a gke pod in the same project) has the only log of the failing requests, with the following message:

```
StatusCodeError: 500 - "\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<title>500 Server Error</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>\n<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n"
```

Rough timeline of the last incident:

- 14:41 - Service is serving requests as expected, producing both log lines each time
- 14:44 to 14:56 - Cloud run logs are empty, every request made to the service (~30) gets the 500 error message
- 14:56 - Cloud run terminates the currently running container instance, (as happens after some inactivity for instance), which is correctly logged by the application (`[INFO] Handling signal: term`)
- 14:58 - Cloud run instantiates a new container instance and starts serving incoming requests (which are logged normally)

The absence of logs during the incident makes it hard to investigate its cause, and at this stage we would be gratefull for any kind of lead.

---

Our service has another known issue, that may or may not be related. The service is designed to avoid multiple replicas, as a single one should be able to handle the load and serve concurrent requests (cloud run concurency = 80), but has a relatively long cold start time (~30s). This leads to 429 errors when a spike of requests comes while no replica is available (because of cloud run hard capping concurrency to 1 during cold start). This issue was somewhat mitigated by allowing some replication (currently maxScale = 3), since each replica can put a request on hold during the cold start, but will require some work on the client side to handle correctly (simple retries after the cold start).

Comment: Can you share your code and how do you log ?

Comment: The code itself is unfortunately private. It is a python gunicorn app outputing both through standard print for debug purposes, and the `logging` package for the log line presented on the post. Remark that the second log line is generated by cloud run, and not our app, and also goes missing during the incident.

Comment: Of course  your code is private! But can you clean it and have a minimal reproducible example? Your issue is strange because even if there is a problem with your logs, the Cloud Run platform logs should continue to work, it's independent of your code!

Comment: Do you see "request logs" that Cloud Run normally logs for any container upon receiving a request for said incidents?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I did not focus on the application code, because as far as I know, it is not executed when the incident happens (serves no request and outputs no log). A minimal example would be a gunicorn app with a sleep(30) on init and a sleep(0.1) when serving requests... As you say It seemed to me that the issue was independant of the app itself...

Comment: @AhmetB-Google Yes, I believe they are the second of the two I mention (logName `projects/XXX/logs/run.googleapis.com/requests`). They usually log every request, but are also absent during the incident...

Comment: When this issue happens, is your Cloud Run instance overloaded? Or receiving more requests than when it doesn't fail? It looks to me like the request couldn't even be allocated in time and thus it's not even logged. Would you consider adding a second container? I say this because 80 is actually the maximum and if there are multiple requests a single container may not be able to handle all of them in time.

Comment: @Ajordat Unfortunately not, there is actually relatively fewer requests during the incidents (about 15 in 10 minutes for instance, while the app routinely serves a couple requests a second during the day). We also allow 3 containers even though a single should be able to serve all requests, and cloud run rarely instanciates the second or third...

Comment: is this work for laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found this [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/172471835) that describes the aforementioned behavior. It seems to happen because a part of Cloud Run thinks that there are already provisioned instances handling the traffic but there aren't. This issue is currently being worked on internally but there's no ETA for a fix at the moment.

The current workaround is to set a maximum number of instances to at least 4.

Comment: Thanks for this link ! I'll try bumping maxScale to 4 and see if it occurs again.

Comment: No problem, do not hesitate to accept the answer if you verify that the issue is gone. This way other people with the same problem will be more aware of the workaround while the issue gets fixed.